# I cannot open or mount a drive that locked with bitlocker

Tags: mount, helpfile

they says there is a application called dislocker can help, I tried, but it is not even installing in my Ubuntu 14.04, I don't that I followed the steps, but the erroro occures, I see there is no specific way for how to install dislocker in ubuntu 14.04, they all telling how to install in Linux like... anyone can help me..? I wanted that drive back, 300gb drive that contains lot, and I am unable to install windows, please help me to mount it on Ubuntu..

Answer (score 0):

According to the [install.txt](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/blob/master/INSTALL.txt) you will need to install these:

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev libpolarssl-dev
```

Then you should create folders, e. g.:

```
sudo mkdir /media/bitlocker /media/mount
```

Then download dislocker source, extract it, get into the src folder

```
cd dislocker/src
```

After that you can install dislocker with:

```
sudo make
```

then run

```
sudo make install
```

Check encrypted partition with fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

(that is a small L letter, not an I or | sign!)

Then Decrypt using:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -pRECOVERY-PASSWORD-GOES-HERE -- /media/bitlocker
```

where the password is a long string of numbers separated with dashes.

In case you don't have recovery password, use your user password in the following form:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -uPASSWORD -- /media/bitlocker
```

If all the above are successful change to root privilege:

```
sudo -i
```

Go to the folder previously created:

```
cd /media/bitlocker
```

Then do the mount:

```
mount -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

Change directory to /media/mount

```
cd /media/mount
```

Then your decrypted files should be here.